# Get the formula of the sum of a sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have a formula $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\beta^t\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}\alpha^i$, so I know the sum is $\frac{\beta}{[(1-\alpha)(1-\alpha\beta)]}$, if it is right. I was thinking of doing $\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}\alpha^i$ first to get $\frac{1-\alpha^{t-1}}{1-\alpha}$, then do the calculation on $\sum^{\infty}_{t=1}\frac{\beta^t(1-\alpha^{t-1})}{1-\alpha}$ to get the answer; but I could not get that formula...  am I on the right track or how should I do the algebra to get the final formula?

Thank you!

Comment: You have a typo, it's $$\frac{\beta}{(1-\beta)(1-\alpha\beta)},$$ assuming $\lvert\beta\rvert < 1$ and $\lvert\alpha\beta\rvert < 1$. If you know why you may do it, changing the order of summation simplifies the computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\beta^t\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}\alpha^i = \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \beta^t\frac{1-\alpha^t}{1-\alpha}= \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\left(\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \beta^t - \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} (\alpha\beta)^t  \right) =\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\left(\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t - \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} (\alpha\beta)^t  \right) $$